# How to Know when a Sprite Effect is Done

Tags: objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit

I am running a sprite effect in an SKScene at certain points.  When the effect is not running I want to pause the scene as otherwise it takes up additional CPU even with no effect running.  I was not able to find a delegate that tells me when the effect stops rendering so that I can pause the scene again.  I could brute force it by having it wait a safe time, but is there a more elegant way to know when the effect is finished?

Setup in viewWillAppear:

```
self.skScene = [EffectsScene sceneWithSize:self.view.frame.size];
[self.skScene setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[self.skView presentScene:self.skScene];
[self.skView setPaused:YES];
```

Method that gets called to run the effect at a specific time:

```
-(void)deleteEffect
{
    if (shouldRunDeleteEffect)
    {
        [self.skScene smokeEffectAtX:self.view.frame.size.width/2 andY:0];
        [self.skView setPaused:NO];
        shouldRunDeleteEffect = NO;
    }
}
```

The actual scene details:

```
-(void)smokeEffectAtX:(float)x andY:(float)y
{
    SKEmitterNode *emitter =  [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SmokeEffect" ofType:@"sks"]];
    emitter.position = CGPointMake(x,y);
    emitter.numParticlesToEmit = 1000;
    [self addChild:emitter];
}
```

Comment: It would help if you were more specific on what kind of effect you are running and with what method (SKEffectsNode, Core Image, etc...)

Comment: It is a simple smoke effect using SKEmitterNode.  I will post some code in my OP as at first I thought this might be a generic question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method creates an SKEmitterNode, calculates how long the emitter will take to run based on its properties and the duration parameter, and adds an SKAction to the emitter to remove it from the scene after it is done running.

```
- (void) newSmokeNodeAtPosition:(CGPoint)position withDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    SKEmitterNode *emitter =  [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SmokeEffect" ofType:@"sks"]];

    emitter.position = position;

    // Calculate the number of particles we need to generate based on the duration
    emitter.numParticlesToEmit = duration * emitter.particleBirthRate;

    // Determine the total time needed to run this effect.
    NSTimeInterval totalTime = duration + emitter.particleLifetime + emitter.particleLifetimeRange/2;
    // Run action to remove the emitter from the scene
    [emitter runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction waitForDuration:totalTime],
                                            [SKAction removeFromParent]]]
            completion:^{
                // Add code here to run when emitter is done
                self.scene.paused = YES;
            }];
    [self addChild:emitter];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a very interesting solution.  However, the calculation is not turning out to be very close.  If I enter say 5 seconds as the duration the rest of calculation is suggesting that the total time is 55 seconds.  However, visually the effect seems to end in about 10 seconds.  So it is waiting substantially (relatively speaking) longer before it goes to a pause.

Comment: I have found that setting the particle lifetime to equal duration is the best way to go.  Essentially using the above formula this gives a 10 second timer for the effect which visually is correct.  The formula given in the sample code above breaks down when the duration is less than the particle's given lifetime.  Hence it would take say a 50 second particle lifetime and add 5 second duration to come up with 55 seconds.  However, as described the effect is really just 10 seconds in length in the given example.

Comment: Also need to add that just pausing the scene is not enough for the CPU to drop.  The actual SKView needs to be paused. This is my fault as I used the word "scene" in my description when I should have said "view".  My code though does use view.  Sorry for the confusion but it is indeed the view.

Comment: The duration parameter doesn't not determine the total time the effect will take to complete. It controls how long the emitter will produce particles. The total time must include the lifetime of the particles. If it's not included, the particles will be removed from the scene when its parent (the emitter) is removed.

Comment: The problem comes though when the lifetime is so much more than the duration.  When the emitter is removed the particles shortly are gone from a visual perspective.  As mentioned with a duration of 5 and a lifetime of 50 it believes particles are still showing up to 55 seconds later when in reality nothing can be seen after 10 seconds.

Comment: Why are you setting the lifetime of the particle to 50 seconds when it is no longer visible after 10 seconds? The lifetime property needs to be set appropriately for the effect.

Comment: I was just giving an example.  I have not seen any best practices when it comes to this per effect and likely it is a result of different things such as speed and device side.  However, as noted it seems best to make it equal to duration for this case and calculation.  Perhaps there is some best practice calculation for lifetime.  Thanks again, I appreciate the help.

Comment: The calculations are correct. If you set the properties of the emitter correctly (using the emitter editor), it will determine the duration of the effect appropriately.